# No food in the fridge

Tags: riddle, english

What eight letters did the little boy say when, whilst looking for an afternoon  snack, he realized that there was no food in the fridge?

Hint:

> ???C????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> OGICURMT = Oh gee, I see you are empty.

Comment: [Alternatively, OG = Original Gangster :-o](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71/gilles)